# Having problem with plus sign, it converts into ascii after sending email

Tags: c#, html-email

When running the following code the script part **`<script type="application/json+trustpilot">`** converts into **`<script type="application/json&#43;trustpilot">`**.
If isBodyHTML is set to false the plus sign appear correctly (meaning not showing `&#43;`) but not in HTML format (which is needed).

Did anyone else had similar problem?

I am doing this in C# inside a SSIS 2012 project.
Already tried all encoding formats, like default, unicode, ...

```
private void sendEmail(string SendMailTo, string SendMailSubject, string SendMailBody)
{
    string sqldbaEmail = "myemail@mail.com";
    string newSqldbaEmail = "anotheremail@mail.com";

    // email sender hardcoded because cannot send email with other credentials
    MailMessage myHtmlFormattedMail = new MailMessage(sqldbaEmail, newSqldbaEmail, SendMailSubject, "");

    myHtmlFormattedMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    myHtmlFormattedMail.Body = SendMailBody;

    myHtmlFormattedMail.Bcc.Add(SendMailTo);

    myHtmlFormattedMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    // Create a SMTP client to send the email
    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential(sqldbaEmail, "password");

    mySmtpClient.Port = 25;// 587;//2525; // If you want to use a different portnumber instead of the default. Else remove this line.
    mySmtpClient.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    mySmtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
    mySmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

    // Sends email
    mySmtpClient.Send(myHtmlFormattedMail);
}
```

[image: enter code here]

Thanks for looking.

Comment: `the script part` what script, I don't see it in the code?

Comment: Have you tried setting the content type, for example: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />`? Please show the `SendMailBody` data... It's definitely an encoding issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

> "Adding {scripts}{/scripts} before the opening  tag keeps the
>   code there."

https://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/50034-trustpilot-afs-2/